# AMP animation on scroll

Tags: animation, amp-html

Want to start animation while scrolling the image only once. How can I do that? "Is amp-position-observer" must need for animate on the scroll?

```
<div class="section4">
    <amp-position-observer on="enter:slideTransition2.start" intersection-ratios="0.1" layout="nodisplay"></amp-position-observer>
    <amp-img layout="responsive" alt="A view of the sea" class="eboardimg" src="/images/simbli-screens.png" width="969" height="376"></amp-img>
    <amp-animation id="slideTransition2" layout="nodisplay">
        <script type="application/json">{
            "duration": "500ms",
            "fill": "both",
            "iterations": "1",
            "animations": [{
                "selector": ".eboardimg",
                "keyframes": [
                  { "transform": "translateY(20%)" },
                  { "transform": "translateY(0)" }
                ]
            }]
        }
        </script>
     </amp-animation>
     <a href="#" class="ampstart-btn LMbtn LMbtn4 travel-input-big rounded center bold white block col-12" >
          LEARN MORE ABOUT THE CORE FOUR
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have to use amp-position-observer with  **`amp-animation`** to fully implement what you want to achieve. You can also check their sample for [Basics of scrollbound effects](https://ampbyexample.com/visual_effects/basics_of_scrollbound_effects/) which shows a fidget spinner to spin every scroll attempt. This sample will help you understand how to maximize the usage of **`amp-position-observer`** combined with **`amp-animation`**.

Comment: @Mr.rebot Thanks for your response! The images need to animate only when the page load for the first time. Using these scrollbound effects images animate each time when scroll happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave the first keyframe out of the animation - If you only have one keyframe, it will animate from whatever the current value is to the value of the only keyframe.

You can read more about amp animations at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation

So you'll want to do something like this:

In the style area:

```
.eboardimg{
   transform:translateY(20%);
}
```

On the main page:

```
<div class="section4">
    <amp-position-observer on="enter:slideTransition2.start" intersection-ratios="0.1" layout="nodisplay"></amp-position-observer>
    <amp-img layout="responsive" alt="A view of the sea" class="eboardimg" src="/images/simbli-screens.png" width="969" height="376"></amp-img>
    <amp-animation id="slideTransition2" layout="nodisplay">
        <script type="application/json">{
            "duration": "500ms",
            "fill": "both",
            "iterations": "1",
            "animations": [{
                "selector": ".eboardimg",
                "keyframes": [
                  { "transform": "translateY(0%)" }
                ]
            }]
        }
        </script>
     </amp-animation>
     <a href="#" class="ampstart-btn LMbtn LMbtn4 travel-input-big rounded center bold white block col-12" >
          LEARN MORE ABOUT THE CORE FOUR
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/maxpelic/pen/mozRLQ